# Determining Asympotic Notation

Tags: asymptotic-complexity

I have a set of problems where I am given an f(n) and g(n) and I am supposed to determine where f(n) is O(g(n)), Ω(g(n)) or Θ(g(n))

And I must also determine the c(s) and n0 for the correct relationship.

How do I get started on a problem like this?

Here's an example for the kind of problem I am given

f(n)= lg(n^2)   g(n)=n lg(n)

Answer (score 1):

You need to reduce f(n) to a form that makes it easy to compare to g(n).  For your case:

> f(n) = log(n<sup>2</sup>)
>        f(n) = 2 log(n)

That should be enough to answer your problem for that example - the process is going to be pretty much the same for the rest of the set.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using limits as follows

Limit as n tends to infinity(sorry i have no idea how to produce mathematical equations here)
of f(n)/g(n)

If the value obtained is

**A constant** then `f(n) = Θ(g(n))`

**Infinity** then `f(n) = Ω(g(n))`

**Zero** then `f(n)= O(g(n))`